# Netbeans C++ not printing UTF-8 characters

Tags: c++, netbeans, unicode, utf-8, netbeans-8.1

Here is the very simple C++ code:

```
char a00 = 'Z';
char a01 = '\u0444';
char a02[5] = {'H','e','l','l','o'};
char a03[] = {'W','o','r','l','d','\0','Z','Z'};

cout << "Simple char: " << a00
        << "\nUTF-8 char: " << a01
        << "\nFull char array: " << a02
        << "\n2nd in char array: " << a02[1]
        << "\nWith null character: " << a03 << endl;
```

My problem is when Netbeans 8.1 tries to show the output of such a program, it does not create the UTF-8 character.

The character should look like this: ф (see: [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0444/index.htm))

Instead, I get the following output:

[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLMQ2.png)

I have tried adding `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `netbeans_default-options` inside the `netbeans.conf` file located at inside the `etc` folder. It made no difference.

Comment: Very few `utf-8` characters fit into a single `char`. Most need two or three bytes. Try putting it in a string: `std::string s = "\u0444";`

Comment: @Galik Yep, that solved my problem perfectly. If you create an answer, I will be able to accept it and close this question. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UTF-8` is a *multibyte* character encoding which means most of the characters occupy several bytes. So a single `char` is not enough to hold most `UTF-8` characters.

You can store them in a string like this:

```
std::string s = "\u0444";
```